# Wifi adapter is not recognized even in lshw

Tags: networking, wifi, drivers, kali-linux, usb

Having problem with Wi-Fi adapter connection.

I have a newly installed Kali 2020.1 in my VirtualBox. Kernel 5.4.0, XFCE 4.14.2 (already done update and upgrade)

My problem is that the system doesn't recognize my Wi-Fi adapter:

```
kali@kali:\~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for kali:
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 3
bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
logical name: eth0
version: 02
serial: 08:00:27:1f:30:76
size: 1Gbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 32 bits
clock: 66MHz
capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 
driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.0.2.15 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
resources: irq:19 memory:f8200000-f821ffff ioport:d020(size=8)

kali@kali:\~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can’t use host machine wifi adapter in virtualbox.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox does not offer a WiFi adapter to any VMs, it's only Ethernet adapters, i.e. wired ones.

The only way that you could access a WiFi network over WiFi would be to use a USB WiFi adapter, which 1) you'd have to capture in your VM, and 2) you wouldn't be able to use on your host.

You can use **Bridged Adapter**

VirtualBox -> Menu Bar -> Devices -> Network -> Network Settings -> Attached to (Select Bridged Adapter) -> Name (Select Wireless)

Read here: https://askubuntu.com/a/282036/456907

Comment: Its OK to only use wifi adapter in VM only. But how? I did select usb in virtualbox before open the VM and lshw still doesnt see my network adapter.

Comment: The steps are clearly mentioned here => https://askubuntu.com/a/282036/456907

Comment: Thanks so much guys. It works :)) look like im missing my driver for the exact kernel on my os.